# Setting error msg from one formcontrol to another

Tags: angular, angular-material

this.outPutCtrl and this.optionCtrl are 2 formcontrol

```
  if(this.optionCtrl?.status === 'INVALID') {
```

console.log(this.optionCtrl?.errors) gives {required: true}

I want to set the error from optionCtrl to to outPutCtrl , but when required is coming error message is not setting

```
 this.outPutCtrl.setErrors({ message: this.optionCtrl?.errors?.message })
```

}

Comment: this.optionCtrl?.errors?.message is nothing. the "errors" is an object. If you has a Validators.required the object is `{required:true}`, if you have Validators.minLenth the object is `{minlength: {requiredLength: #, actualLength: #}}`, etc.